# English contracts vs Singapore contracts

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales, singapore

Since Singapore law is based on English common law, would it be feasible to use a pre-exising English Services Agreement wording in Singapore? Could we then amend the wording so it's governed by Singapore law?

Comment: what do you mean by "English Services Agreement wording"?

Comment: You're right. I wasn't very clear. What I meant was could we amend the governing clause? E.g. "This Agreement shall be governed by and construed in accordance with the laws of Singapore."

Comment: Asking good questions takes effort. I see none here.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share your thoughts @Greendrake! Have a lovely day. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Could we then amend the wording so it's governed by Singapore law?**

Yes, in fact you could amend the wording of any document to make it compliant with a relevant law because you have amended it to be so.

Answer (score 1):

> Could we then amend the wording so it's governed by Singapore law?

Your reference to "*a pre-existing [...] wording*" makes it unclear whether you mean (1) adopting and/or adapting clauses of some unrelated contract(s) in order to create a new one, or (2) modifying a contract which currently binds the parties. Both approaches are lawful as long as the parties agree to do so, since what matters is that the contract reflects the parties' intent.

It is unclear why you think that specifically amending or modifying the clause about *choice of law* could be unlawful. There might be some details which are missing from your description, thereby preventing us from identifying what exactly you need to know.